# Has anyone attempted to study the history and evolution of specific jazz "licks"?

Tags: jazz, motif

Has anyone attempted to study the history and evolution of specific jazz "licks" ? For example, Louis Armstrong played this phrase or snippet or riff. Here is how it evolved...here is how Basie's band used it, here is how Roy Eldridge took it and added to it, and Dizzy, and Bird, and Trane, and and and...

Similar to the approach a formal linguist would take.

Comment: This is too broad to answer right now. I mean, the answer could be "Yes, they have," which isn't really helpful, or "no, they haven't" (which would require surveying all the literature to say for sure. Also, such a broad study would itself be hard. There are a lot of licks out there! More often, a study *of a specific work* will talk about how it quotes itself or previous work, when it does so intentionally. When it doesn't...

Comment: When it doesn't, I'm not sure we can trace an "evolution." if A does something, and later B does something similar without intentional quotation... then maybe it was subconscious, maybe it was coincidence, and who's even to say how similar it has to be to "count" as "the same" riff? Much easier (and more useful?) to stick to conscious influence.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because an answer that simply lists studies is off-topic here, and one that actually does the study would be way too broad.

Comment: William T. Dargan, in "Lining Out the Word", traces some details of Coltrane's music all the way back to the "Dr. Watts" singing tradition in African American churches. He argues persuasively that the tradition includes several features that have carried through styles of melodic embellishment in gospel, blues, jazz, and pop.

Comment: That is a fascinating direction to look, but I think much too vague for my query. This could relate Trane's music to the black Baptist church and entire culture, but I'm thinking about very specific phrases, licks, riffs, and would love to see them traced backward and forward. Maybe I'll try it...thank you for your response!

Comment: One more comment about Coltrane and the church: he does famously "preach" using his horn in at least one instance which is the Psalm section of A Love Supreme. There is a long prayer of sorts which he wrote for the album notes, and in Psalm he "plays that prayer" with his saxophone, syllable by syllable, word by word.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thanks for your thoughts Andy. I believe the short answer is no one has successfully pursued this undertaking. I would NOT be expecting any kind of comprehensive study. That could be nearly infinite. More like: a dozen licks that can be traced backward and forward and that make up part of the DNA of the jazz improvisatory vocabulary and syntax.